# Error al llamar Una vista con chart.js error Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js

Hola necesito llamar mendiante load de jquery una vista en Template.php pero en la vista hay un canvas que contiene un grafico pero el grafico muestra el siguiente error? `

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

`

agroquimicos.php

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="box box-solid box-success">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">IMPORTAR ARCHIVO INSUMOS</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <span class="label label-primary">imp</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

div contenido Template.php

```
<li class=""><a href="#" id = 'agroquimicos'><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> <span>ENTRADAS ECM</span></a></li>

<section class="content container-fluid" id="contenido">

  </section>
```

agroquimicos.js

```
$(document).on('click','#agroquimicos',function(event){
      $('#contenido').load('pages/agroquimicos.php');
      var ctx = $("#myChart");
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          // The type of chart we want to create
          type: 'line',

          // The data for our dataset
          data: {
              labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
              datasets: [{
                  label: "My First dataset",
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
              }]
          },

          // Configuration options go here
          options: {}
      });
    });
```

footer de template.php

```
<script src="../public/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='../public/node_modules_js/chart/dist/Chart.js'></script>
  <script src="../public/js/graficos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

ya cambie el `<div id="myChart" style="height: 250px;"></div>` pero sigue sin mostrarme el grafico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te invito a leer la documentación de jQuery sobre el método load() http://api.jquery.com/load/
Ya que este método para cargar un recurso, tiene que hacerlo de manera asíncrona.
Por lo tanto, el código que tienes después de

> $('#contenido').load('pages/agroquimicos.php');

Se ejecuta antes de que el contenido del template se cargue en la página.

La solución a este problema es usar el callback del método load() de esta manera:

```
$('#contenido').load('pages/agroquimicos.php', function() {
      var ctx = $("#myChart");
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          // The type of chart we want to create
          type: 'line',

          // The data for our dataset
          data: {
              labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
              datasets: [{
                  label: "My First dataset",
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
              }]
          },

          // Configuration options go here
          options: {}
      });
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esa era la solucion Saludos

Answer (score 0):

el problema ocurre en tu archivo 'agroquimicos.php' en el debes cambiar tu:

```
<div id="myChart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Por:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

En la documentación de [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) especifica que debes utilizar la etiqueta `<canvas>`

Comment: Ya lo cambie pero sigue sin mostrar

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error?

Comment: Si este error en la consola Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Comment: Parece ser que el selector no esta funcionando, si agregas esta línea antes de crear tu Chart: console.log($("#myChart")); , ¿Te imprime algo en la consola?